# Code compiles in VSCode but not on ubuntu server

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, mern, ubuntu-20.04, npm-build

I'm new to deploying an app, as this is the first time I've done it. I'm trying to deploy my mern app to an aws ec2 instance with the intention to use mongodb atlas, I'm using a ubuntu 20.04 server.

I'm following this guide https://keithweaverca.medium.com/setting-up-mern-stack-on-aws-ec2-6dc599be4737 and I've got to part after I've pulled my github repo to the ubuntu server, everything is working up to yet, I skipped the mongodb section of the guide, as I have already created a mongodb cluster.

I'm not sure what to do now, my repo folder is split like this...

```
- frontend
  - build
  - public
  - src
    - Components
    - images
    ... other files in src
  - package.json
- backend
  - server.js
  - models
  - routes
  - package.json
  ... a few other irrelevant files (node_modules, etc.)
```

Although the guide doesn't say to, don't I need to run 'npm run build' in the frontend directory? after I've ran 'npm install'?

If so, my code isn't compiling and I'm not sure why, it says there is a memory leak, and javascript overload.

I know this is a lot of questions, without much detail, but I don't even understand this well enough to give more info. Any questions please ask. I just need to know what commands to run after I've pulled my code from the github repo.